# going crazy. Simple alert when checkbox is checked with jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, alert, checked, click

I cannot get a simple alert to fire when a checkbox is clicked/checked. I have been scratching my head wondering why I cant get it to work and I know it is going to be something simple... So, what am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#test1').click(function(){
alert('clicked');
});
</script>

<input type="checkbox" id="test1" value="test1" name="test1" value="-1">test1</input>
```

Comment: Is that the order of your code? Try declaring the `click` handler *after* the checkbox.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not waiting for [DOM ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). If you will, it'll work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#test1').click(function(){
        alert('clicked');
    });
});
</script>

<input type="checkbox" id="test1" value="test1" name="test1" value="1" /> test1
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sanbc/

Comment: Switched it out, didn't work, then found a conflicting library, removed it and it works fine. Thanks for the tip though, Ill make sure to include that on all future attempts.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to wrap it in document.ready() otherwise the click event might be assigned before the element exists.

OR

Make sure the jQuery library is included.

OR

Make sure no other javascript libraries are included, they can mess up the $ object. If they are, replace $ with jQuery.

Try those and get back to me with a comment

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/9dSMM/

Perhaps there is a problem with the DOM not being ready?

Remember to wrap this in a `document.ready`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
 });
```

[More here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

Put your code inside a `$(document).ready` event so that you can be sure the checkbox exists when you try to register an event handler with it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to check the obvious, I've never written any Jquery UI code without this wrapper:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
       //......
     });
```